# How to make a button with 2 conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I'm junior developer in js and learn web-platforn Meteor. I doubt how to make button to change state between true and false (boolean) in one component of document in data base.

For example, I have such document: [{ name: 'Name', surname: 'Surname', active: 'true' }].
I need to be able to change active condition from true to false and vice versa using UI in my app.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you show at least what you have tried so far?

Comment: @GetSet I have user template in /client: <h4>{{first_name}} {{last_name}} <button id='btn-toggle'>{{active}}</button></h4>
Also I add users to db when the server starts in /server directory: User.insert({
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Nickles",
    active: true
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you would need to update the document in the database. 
A good practice is to perform updates on the server side, and in Meteor this is done through Meteor.methods().

In the same file where you create the users when the server is started you would add some code that would look like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
   'toggleActiveStateUser'(userId) {
       const user = User.findOne(userId);
       if (!user) {
           return;
       }
       User.update({_id: userId}, {$set: {'active': !user.active}});
   }
});
```

On your client side code, we can access this code by running the following when we triggering the button event.

```
Meteor.call('toggleActiveStateUser', userId, function(err, result) {console.log(err, result); });
```

In case you are using Blaze Templates you can access the button template in the following way:

```
Template.yourTemplateName.events({
   'click #btn-toggle': function (event, template) {
       console.log('Click event working!');
       const user = Template.instance().data
       // run the Meteor.call function in here.
   }
});
```

In case you want further help you will have to put your code on github so we can see what you are working on and help you further with your adventure into Web development.

Comment: Have just seen your answer. Thanks for it. Actually I've managed to cope with it somehow and that's what I have if interesting https://github.com/alexwerben/react-user-db

Comment: Good to see that you got it to work, only think I want to point out is that you are currently updating the user collection on client side. For just a simple demo app this is no issue, but once you start working on production applications, you would want to perform these functions on server side in order to prevent unauthorized actions on your database.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```js
let doc = [{ name: 'Name', surname: 'Surname', active: 'true' }];

document.querySelector('#btn-toggle').addEventListener('click', () => {
  doc[0].active === 'true' ? doc[0].active = 'false' : doc[0].active = 'true';
  console.log(doc)
});
```

```html
<button id='btn-toggle'>Toggle 'active'</button>
```

Btw, I would use true booleans in an Object, not Strings:

```
let doc = [{ name: 'Name', surname: 'Surname', active: true }];
```

```js
let doc = [{ name: 'Name', surname: 'Surname', active: true }];

document.querySelector('#btn-toggle').addEventListener('click', () => {
  doc[0].active = !doc[0].active;
  console.log(doc)
});
```

```html
<button id='btn-toggle'>Toggle 'active'</button>
```

Comment: what if I have already generated users in data base on server when app starts with command: user.insert() {name: 'Name', surname: 'Surname', active: true};
Should I somehow adapt your code to use user.updateOne({active: true}, {$set: {active: false}});?

Comment: Uff that's a bit difficult without much context, but yes, I would try to write a function updateUser(user) that can update any user, not just 1 specific and that updates in the database. Sadly I don't know syntax for mongodb